# What's the Extended BNF of "<A> -> ab|ac"?

Tags: computer-science, bnf, ebnf

What's the Extended BNF of

```
<A> -> ab|ac
```

? Is it

```
<A> -> a[b|c]
```

or

```
<a>-> a(b|c)
```

Answer (score 1):

The production

```
<a>-> a(b|c)
```

is correct. The notation [ ] means optional.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form